# Is it feasible to get available system memory, disk space, cpu usage of a remote system only providing host name, Login UserId and Password

Tags: java, operating-system, system, remote-access, remote-server

I'm checking the system parameters like CPU Utilisation, Memory utilisation etc of a remote system(Windows server) only by login in to that system remotely(running mstsc). There I provide the inputs like ServerIP or Host name, Port number, Login UserId and Password.

There are Java programs by which we can get the local system's parameter. We can go for building and the deploying such a J2EE application in broadcast mode in the remote server and on calling the services which can return the server system's parameters. But

-> I do not want to install any software/server in remote system.
-> I don't want to deploy J2EE application in remote server. Simply I don't want any change in remote server.

Is there any way to get these parameters of remote servers by Java or any language provided 
only running application from local systems; without touching the Remote system.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

if you can't install a JVM in the remote server, than you cannot run a java program there :-)

what you can do, then, is to automate the routine to connect to the machine, capture input and output, send some commands and retrieve their results, just like you would do with expect for example.

there are some java libraries that behave like expect, such as enchanter, expectj, expect4j, etc.

the tricky part here, of course, is how you're going to connect to these servers. If you can use telnet is easier to automate, because that is only text in and out.